# how to convert the int value into string to show in grid in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have tried the following code and it is giving error

```
var res = (from results in db.JobSearchAgents
                        where results.SiteID == 110 && results.UserID == sess
                        select new Agentlist
                        {
                            JobSearchAgentID = results.JobSearchAgentID.ToString(),

                            EmailAddress = results.EmailAddress,
                            Keywords = results.Keywords,


                            Country = results.Country,
                            zipcode = results.ZipCode,
                            miles = results.Miles.ToString()


                        }).AsEnumerable();
             ViewData["ajax"] = true;
             ViewData["scrolling"] = true;
             ViewData["paging"] = true;
             ViewData["filtering"] = true;
             ViewData["grouping"] = true;
             ViewData["sorting"] = true;
             ViewData["showFooter"] = true;
             //ViewData["searchresults"] = res;

            return View(res);


<%using (Html.BeginForm())
       {%>
       <%=Html.Telerik().Grid(Model).Name("Grid").Columns(columns=>
    {
        columns.Bound(m=>m.Keywords);
        columns.Bound(m=>m.Country);
    }).DataBinding(databinding=>
        {
            databinding.Server().Select("Agentlist","Grid",new
            {
           ajax=ViewData["ajax"]
            });
             databinding.Ajax().Select("Agentlist",
                "Grid").Enabled((bool)ViewData["ajax"]);
        })
        .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Enabled((bool)ViewData["scrolling"]))
        .Sortable(sorting => sorting.Enabled((bool)ViewData["sorting"]))
        .Pageable(paging => paging.Enabled((bool)ViewData["paging"]))
        .Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled((bool)ViewData["filtering"]))
        .Groupable(grouping => grouping.Enabled((bool)ViewData["grouping"]))
        .Footer((bool)ViewData["showFooter"])


           %>
      <%}%>
```

Comment: *It is giving error*. OK, does this error come with an error message or something?

Comment: linq to entities doesnot recognizes the methos system.string.tostring()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error is because your query is trying to execute ToString method in db. using AsEnumerable you can tell the query to execute your methods in c#. you can either change your query to

```
var res = (from results in db.JobSearchAgents
                        where results.SiteID == 110 && results.UserID == sess
                        select result).AsEnumerable().Select(result=>new Agentlist
                        {
                            JobSearchAgentID = results.JobSearchAgentID.ToString(),

                            EmailAddress = results.EmailAddress,
                            Keywords = results.Keywords,


                            Country = results.Country,
                            zipcode = results.ZipCode,
                           miles = results.Miles.ToString()

                        });
```

Or you can bind your columns to telerik grid without calling ToString method. Telerik grid does not require the data to be in string format. Moreover, if you want data to be displayed in specific format you can call Format method when binding to the grid

```
columns.Bound(m=>m.Keywords).Foramt("format string");
```

Comment: By all means. Telerik grid comes with functionality of CRUD. for more info visit http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid?theme=vista